# Excluding some scene elements from bloom effect

Tags: graphic-effects, scenekit, hdr, bloom

I've enabled HDR and bloom effects in my SceneKit app, but I don't want some of the elements in my scene to bloom.

For example, the lighter spots on the skybox are currently glowing.

Is there some way I can stop those elements from glowing selectively?